# Access DB. VBA Query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2013

I am trying to figure out why the following code wont return anything from [Card Lookup 1], 2 or 3.
I know some very basic SQL and virtually no VBA. I appreciate any assistance.

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
Dim SQL As String
    SQL = "SELECT [Master List].[First Name], [Master List].[Last Name], [Master List].[Card Lookup 1], [Master List].[Card Lookup 2], [Master List].[Card Lookup 3], [Master List].ID " _
    & "FROM [Master List]" _
    & "WHERE [First Name] LIKE '*" & Me.txtkeywords & "*' " _
    & "OR [Last Name] LIKE '*" & Me.txtkeywords & "*' " _
    & "OR [Card Lookup 1] LIKE '*" & Me.txtkeywords & "*' " _
    & "OR [Card Lookup 2] LIKE '*" & Me.txtkeywords & "*' " _
    & "OR [Card Lookup 3] LIKE '*" & Me.txtkeywords & "*' " _
    & "OR ID LIKE '*" & Me.txtkeywords & "*' " _
    & "ORDER BY [Master List].[Last Name] "
    
    Me.subUserSearch.Form.RecordSource = SQL
    Me.subUserSearch.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

```
[First Name] = Short Text
[Last Name] = Short Text
[Card Lookup 1] = Number
[Card Lookup 2] = Number
[Card Lookup 3] = Number
[ID] = AutoNumber
```

Expected: User inputs name or number associated with a card Returns match based on name or number entered. In the original code it returns every field fine except Card Lookup 1, 2, or 3 Upon changing the wildcard symbol, it fails to return any data.

Card Lookup 1,2 and,3 are assigned IDcard Numbers.

Comment: Please provide sample data of *Card Lookups* for [mcve] and value used in `Me.txtkeywords`.

Comment: Are the "problem" fields numeric? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108171/how-to-use-like-condition-in-sql-with-numeric-field   `& "OR [Card Lookup 1] & '' LIKE '*" & Me.txtkeywords & "*' " _`

Comment: @TimWilliams
Yes they are numeric.

Answer (score 1):

There is a space missing:

```
& "FROM [Master List]" _
& "WHERE [First Name] LIKE '*" & Me.txtkeywords & "*' " _
```

... results in:

```
FROM [Master List]WHERE [First Name] LIKE '*foo*'
```

Insert space here:

```
& "FROM [Master List] " _
```

Do you know the debug console in VBA editor? For debugging the first step is always looking at the results:

```
debug.print SQL
```

Also, you might want to add error handling so you can see the actual error message causing your empty results in the debug console:

```
Private Sub xxx()
on error goto fErr

' query action here

fExit:
' do your cleanups here
exit sub

fErr:
debug.print err.description
resume fExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for seeing the space.
I have no idea about the debug console.
First time really using Access...

Comment: @JamesFleming see [Where does VBA Debug.Print log to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916287/where-does-vba-debug-print-log-to)

Comment: @JamesFleming if you liked this answer, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As noted here: [How to use LIKE condition in SQL with numeric field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108171/how-to-use-like-condition-in-sql-with-numeric-field)

You can't use `Like` with a numeric field without casting the value to a string (eg. by concatenating its value with '')

```vb
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
Dim SQL As String
    SQL = "SELECT [Master List].[First Name], [Master List].[Last Name], [Master List].[Card Lookup 1], [Master List].[Card Lookup 2], [Master List].[Card Lookup 3], [Master List].ID " _
    & "FROM [Master List] " _
    & "WHERE [First Name] LIKE '*" & Me.txtkeywords & "*' " _
    & "OR [Last Name] LIKE '*" & Me.txtkeywords & "*' " _
    & "OR [Card Lookup 1] & '' LIKE '*" & Me.txtkeywords & "*' " _
    & "OR [Card Lookup 2] & '' LIKE '*" & Me.txtkeywords & "*' " _
    & "OR [Card Lookup 3] & '' LIKE '*" & Me.txtkeywords & "*' " _
    & "OR ID LIKE '*" & Me.txtkeywords & "*' " _
    & "ORDER BY [Master List].[Last Name] "
    
    Me.subUserSearch.Form.RecordSource = SQL
    Me.subUserSearch.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.
I understand how that is supposed to work. After applying the changes. I enter "371". It correctly returns values in the ID field that contain "371" but still does not return anything from the Card Lookup fields.

Comment: I'm not an access user, so maybe there's something specific to your "lookup" fields which is an issue here?  Are they just "regular" numeric fields?

Comment: In design view they are listed as number with a field size of long integer.

Comment: Are you using keywords match the "id" of your lookup, or the "value" ?

Comment: I dont think I fully understand the question. However, I think it should be the value.

Comment: The "id" is typically a numeric value (1,3,5, etc) whereas the "value" would typically be a text value ("red", "green", "blue") etc.  If you want to query on the text values then you need to join the lookup table(s) in your query SQL.