# Why do the % operators in the query not work for strings containing numbers? (JPA)

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have the following query:

```
 @Query("SELECT d FROM CarportLocationEntityView d WHERE d.externalId LIKE %:filterCriteria% OR lower(d.carportName) LIKE lower(concat('%',:filterCriteria,'%')) ")
    List<CarportLocationEntityView> filterCarportList(@Param("filterCriteria") String filterCriteria);
```

This query searches two columns in the database:

1. externalId
2. carportName

Both columns are of type string, where in externalId always a number is specified as string. if I apply the query and enter a part of carportName then I get the correct results.
However, if I filter for an externalId and enter only a part of the externalId in the parameter then I get no data.

Ex: localhost:8080/filter?filterCriteria=100
Here I get no data back.

But if I filter for the whole externalId
localhost:8080/filter?filterCriteria=1000000
then I get the matching data set.

Why do the % operators in the query not work for strings containing numbers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use LIKE condition in SQL with numeric field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108171/how-to-use-like-condition-in-sql-with-numeric-field)

Comment: unfortunately not really. This question is about actual SQL queries. I am using a JPA query. But thanks for your help

Comment: it's the same with JPA

Comment: so I tried the solutions and they did not work. Neither >= or concate nor strval. The difference from my problem to this question is that I have a string field where I enter a number and not a numeric field.

Comment: How would you write the SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
@Query("SELECT d FROM CarportLocationEntityView d WHERE d.externalId LIKE %:#{#filterCriteria}% OR lower(d.carportName) LIKE %:#{#filterCriteria.toLowerCase()}% ")
List<CarportLocationEntityView> filterCarportList(@Param("filterCriteria") String filterCriteria);
```

Ref:

- [Using SpEL Expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.5.6/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions) - Spring Data JPA Reference Documentation

See Also:

- [How to log SQL statements in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30118683/4506703)